# Name Excel Worksheet using Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, for-loop, worksheet

I'm trying to name create a new excel worksheet and have the variable name come from an array. Code...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
string[] Numbers = new string[12] { "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"};
string[] Months = new string[12] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
            for (int i = 0; i < Months.Length; i++)
            {
                newWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets.Add();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet Numbers[i] = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets["Sheet" + i];
                Numbers[i].Name = Months[i];
            }
```

I am trying to have the variable name of the new worksheet be the number from the array "Numbers". I get an error when trying since it thinks I am trying to declare an array. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you expecting sheet name with sequence of month and date? and if possible post more code snippet what you tried.

Comment: @DInesh AG I want the variable name of my sheet to be a number and the name the user sees to be the month. For example, variable name = "1" and name user sees = "Jan". Also I tried adding some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing. You are using the name Month for two different arrays

```
string[] Months
```

and

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet Months[i]
```

Ending up with this very confusing code

```
Months[i].Name = Months[i];
```

Rename one of your arrays.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I renamed the array.